# Tilix -e nvim doesn't load my bash/zsh environment / profile

Tags: zsh, xfce, nvim, tilix

I put `tilix -e nvim` command for shortcut in my xfce. Then I do `:!echo $PATH` and doesn't get my regular `$PATH` value. The same for `:echo $PATH`. If I put command in whisker menu, I got the same.

But when I run it from my shell `$PATH` is loaded as expected.

How can I pass my `.profile` or `.zshrc` to tilix when run it through xfce shortcut or whisker menu?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (if I understand You correctly), when I tried to run NVM under Tilix.
NVM's commands put in `.profile` file didn't made any effect in Tilix.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I had to move these three lines into `.bashrc`...

Comment: I decided to switch to Arch :))